# Read & write text to a separate file on the hard drive

Tags: c#, xna

Having a problem with my code here. My code is supposed to (what I want it to do) is after the game ends a spritefont appears that allows you to enter text and once that text is entered then it would write that score to the text file. But of course it does not do that. If anyone could help, would be grand.

**EDIT**
This is what I am using to try and input text after the game is over (Game is Space Invaders) Perhaps there is something wrong here also.

```
SpriteFont Label;
string txt = ".";
Keys PrevKey;
string[] HighScores = new string[5];
int count = 0;

KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
Keys[] k = ks.GetPressedKeys();
Keys tempKey = Keys.None;
string keyChar = "";

foreach (Keys q in k)
{
    Keys currentKey = q;

    if (ks.IsKeyUp(PrevKey))
    {
        if (!(q == Keys.None))
        {
            switch (q)
            {
                case Keys.Space: keyChar = " "; break;
                case Keys.Delete: txt = ""; break;
                case Keys.Back: txt = txt.Remove(txt.Length - 1); break;
                case Keys.Enter: HighScores[count] = txt; count++; txt = "";
                                 if (count == 5) count = 0; break;
                case Keys.End: WriteScores(); break;
                case Keys.Home: ReadScores(); break;
                default: keyChar = q.ToString(); break;
            }
            txt += keyChar;
        }
    }

    if (currentKey != Keys.None && ks.IsKeyDown(currentKey))
    {
        tempKey = currentKey;
    }
}

PrevKey = tempKey;
base.Update(gameTime);
}
}
}
}

public void WriteScores()
{
    StreamWriter Rite = new StreamWriter(@"C:\TheScores.txt");      
    for (int i = 0; i < HighScores.Length; i++)
    {
        Rite.WriteLine(HighScores[i]);
    }  
    Rite.Close();
}

public void ReadScores()
{
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\TheHighScores.txt"))
    {
        StreamReader Reed = new StreamReader(@"C:\TheScores.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < HighScores.Length; i++)
        {
            txt += Reed.ReadLine() + "\n";
        }
        Reed.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the path to a user folder like Documents or AppData.   Your code as it is will throw an access violation for insufficient permissions unless you run your program as administrator, as the root of C:\ is only available from an elevated context.

Comment: I have added a section of code in my initial question to try make things clearer.